# Sencha Touch AJAX call to MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-2, sencha-touch

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
                url: '/Home/GetMessagesMobile',
                callbackKey: 'callback',
                params: {
                    lat: geoip_latitude(),
                    lng: geoip_longitude(),
                    rad: 1,
                    sType: 0,
                    flow: 1,
                    lastId: 0,
                    lastRow: 0,
                    uniqueify: Math.random()
                },
                callback: function (data) {
                    var messages = data;
                    alert(messages);
                    home.update(messages); // refresh messages
                }
            });
```

I can debug and hit the breakpoint of my MVC action, and confirm that data is being returned by the action, however, the `alert` never gets shown, and nothing happens on the client side. Looks like it's not entering the `callback` for some reason.

Do I need to make this request different? I'm returning a `Json` result from the action. Here is the code:

```
return Json(retval);
```

Where `retval` is a list of objects that match the html template parameters elsewhere in the sencha code. Even if that part doesn't match though, I should at least be able to see the alert right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably make a cross-domain request, in that case, you must use JSONP.

And using JSONP, makes impossible to use `return Json(object)` from the controller.

Check the JSONP class in the [API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/). There is a example for ASP.NET.
You can use in [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class to serialize an object to JSON.
(In fact, Json method is using this class in the back).

The idea is you have to return something like this:

```
var myJson = {success:true};
someRandomMethod(myJson); // someRandomMethod is the callback parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `JSONP`, you should use `Ext.util.JSON`

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) works in another way, returning JavaScript instead of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Sencha/Ext a lot, so I could be way off base here, but shouldn't that be:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: '/Home/GetMessagesMobile',
  params: {
    lat: geoip_latitude(),
    lng: geoip_longitude(),
    rad: 1,
    sType: 0,
    flow: 1,
    lastId: 0,
    lastRow: 0,
    uniqueify: Math.random()
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```